# How to modify Mouse Input WDF Filter Driver (Moufiltr) to work for USB mice?

Tags: windows, inf, wdf, input-devices, filter-driver

[This filter driver example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Moufiltr-WDF-Version-fb57f5de) works well for PS2 devices, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work for USB mice on x64. Any ideas?

Is this an INF file question? Or will code changes be necessary, too?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding "HID_DEVICE_SYSTEM_MOUSE" as one of the supported Hardware ID? You might also want to check out the this post: http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=262117

Comment: No, didn't try that because I am not familiar with INF files. Where should this be added? But thanks a lot, the link looks very promising.

Comment: This should be added under the [Manufacturer] section. But I would highly recommend learning more about INF files before modifying it. This is a good place to start: http://www.wd-3.com/archive/InfFiles.htm.